# What follows "besides" when it means "in addition to"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Would the main subject be considered plural when "besides" is added to the sentence?

For example:

*A mother is telling her daughter:*

> Me, besides your father, (**think/s**) that your attitude these past few
>   days is unbearable and very rude indeed.

I know the sentence can be structured in other ways that may be more suitable, but I'm intending the situation more than the sentence (example) itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the object pronoun "me" as the subject of a sentence - you should use "I". I would also reverse the order of "Besides your father" and "I", as this sounds more natural to me. I would also change the tense to present perfect where you describe something happening over the past few days. And to answer your question, you should use *think*, not *thinks*. *thinks* only works for the third person singular, and you are talking about yourself - this is the first person singular. This is how I would phrase it:

> Besides your father, *I* **think** that your attitude these past few days *has been* unbearable and very rude indeed.

However, if you switched it so that "your father" was the main subject, you would use *thinks*:

> Besides me, *your father* **thinks** that your attitude these past few days *has been* unbearable and very rude indeed.

In the above case you would use "me" because it's the object of the preposition "besides". In general I might use *along with* instead of *besides* in either of these sentences, but that could just be my personal preference.

Comment: It seems as it is unpreferable in my current structure, but that may be because of the tons of grammatical mistakes I did. So, if I said (another example): "Her sister, besides her, **thinks** that...", then would it be acceptable and correct?

Comment: @TasneemZh In your new version, I would normally interpret it as a typo for *beside*, meaning that her sister was *standing next to her*. To have *besides* convey the meaning you want, you should start the sentence with it—not use it parenthetically.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct, because in this case “her sister” is the subject and takes the third-person singular verb form (*thinks*). The “besides X” phrase is not part of the subject and is irrelevant to the verb conjugation. But if you said “She and her sister...” then you would use *think* because this is a third-person plural subject.

Comment: I meant to write "... grammatical mistakes I **made**" — another grammar issue.

Comment: @JasonBassford | If that's the case, then I would better avoid it in that questionable structure.

Comment: I agree. Thank you so much for providing such a clear explanation and answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.  "Besides" means "separate from", and the verb should be conjugated relative to the main subject.  While "besides" can also imply "in addition to", whatever you want to add should be considered a distinct subject.

In your example, I prefer to put the "besides" clause before the subject:

> Besides what your father thinks, I **think** your attitude ...

but this is personal preference.  It's not wrong to do it the other way (although "me" is not the correct first-person subject.  It should be "I").

Note I also changed it to "what your father thinks" so that the statement compares similar things.  You can write a sentence that focuses on the people:

> Besides your father and me, your grandmother **is** also going to your graduation.

Comment: But it would imply the meaning of "in addition to" in my current structure, wouldn't it?

Comment: @TasneemZh  Yes ... that's what I said, didn't I?  Perhaps I don't understand your objection.

Comment: You said it means "separate from" but it **can** also imply "in addition to". So, it has a probability to mean the opposite of what I want the sentence to mean. That's why I've needed to make sure that even in its current structure, would it indicate that?

Comment: @TasneemZh  It woudl be "in addition to" if you both think the same thing, *"In addition to what your father thinks, I also think that ..."*  It would be "different from" if you think different things.